# Laravel 5 Class 'form' not found

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I have added "illuminate/html": "5.*" to composer.json and ran "composer update".

```
  - Installing illuminate/html (v5.0.0)
    Loading from cache
```

I ran this command in the root of the website. I modified the composer.json file in /root/.composer... and in the root of the project and neither have made a difference.

This downloaded the class and it seemed to install. I have added the following to file *config/app.php*.

```
    'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',

    'Form'      => 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade',
    'Html'      => 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade',
```

I think I have an idea what is wrong, but I don’t know how to fix it. My install is in '/var/www/website'. I have checked the file path and the *Html* folder does not exist.

```
"/var/www/website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Html"
```

I was able to find the class files, but in a different directory.

```
"/var/www/website/vendor/illuminate/html"
```

I manually copied the files over to the main Laravel *illuminate/html* folder, but this hasn't worked either.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This may not be the answer you're looking for, but I'd recommend using the now community maintained repository [Laravel Collective Forms & HTML](http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html) as the main repositories have been deprecated.

Laravel Collective is in the process of updating their website.  You may [view the documentation on GitHub](https://github.com/LaravelCollective/docs/blob/5.6/html.md) if needed.

Comment: Any idea why this was removed in v5?

Comment: seems they want to make it more lightweight and let people add things only when they need them.

Comment: Have they noticed it in the upgrade guide or somewhere else ? did not see it.

Comment: Thanks didn't know this new to laravel and its still in the main docs so I had no idea this wasn't in v5.

Answer (score 99):

`Form` is not included in `laravel` **5.0** as it was on **4.0**, steps to include it:

Begin by installing `laravelcollective/html` package through `Composer`. Edit your project's `composer.json` file to require:

```
"require": {
    "laravelcollective/html": "~5.0"
}
```

Next, update `composer` from the Terminal:

```
composer update
```

---

Next, add your new provider to the `providers` array of `config/app.php`:

```
'providers' => [
  // ...
  'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
  // ...
],
```

---

Finally, add two class aliases to the `aliases` array of `config/app.php`:

```
'aliases' => [
// ...
  'Form' => 'Collective\Html\FormFacade',
  'Html' => 'Collective\Html\HtmlFacade',
// ...
],
```

---

At this point, `Form` should be working

[Source](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html)

---

**Update** `Laravel 5.8` (2019-04-05):

In `Laravel 5.8`, the `providers` in the `config/app.php` can be declared as:

```
Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
```

instead of:

```
'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
```

This notation is the same for the aliases.

Comment: The SRC link has updated. https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html

From 5.0 to 5.3 they changed the providers and aliases sections. 

Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class, for providers 

and then 'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class, and 'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class, for aliases.

Comment: Why does it not make it clear on the laravel docs that the rather basic component is not included by default.

Answer (score 35):

Just type the following command in terminal at the project directory and installation is done according the Laravel version:

```
composer require "laravelcollective/html"
```

Then add these lines in `config/app.php`

```
'providers' => [
    // ...
    Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
    // ...
],

'aliases' => [
    // ...
   'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
   'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
    // ...
],
```

Comment: Awesome answer. Tnq so much

Comment: works for me, this confog should be used: <root>\app\config\app.php

Answer (score 25):

You can also try running the following commands in Terminal or Command:

1. `composer dump-auto` or `composer dump-auto -o`
2. `php artisan cache:clear`
3. `php artisan config:clear`

The above worked for me.

Answer (score 16):

There is an update to this for Laravel 5.2.  Notice this is a slightly different format from what is indicated above.

Begin by installing this package through Composer. Edit your project's composer.json file to require laravelcollective/html.

```
"require": {
    "laravelcollective/html": "5.2.*"
}
```

Next, update Composer from the Terminal:

```
composer update
```

Next, add your new provider to the providers array of config/app.php:

```
  'providers' => [
    // ...
    Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
    // ...
  ],
```

Finally, add two class aliases to the aliases array of config/app.php:

```
  'aliases' => [
    // ...
      'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
      'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
    // ...
  ],
```

After making this update this code worked for me on a new installation of Laravel 5.2:

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'foo/bar')) !!}
    //
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

I got this information here: https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html

Answer (score 5):

Begin by installing this package through Composer. Run the following from the terminal:

```
composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.3.0"
```

Next, add your new provider to the providers array of config/app.php:

```
'providers' => [
    // ...
    Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
    // ...
  ],
```

Finally, add two class aliases to the aliases array of config/app.php:

```
'aliases' => [
    // ...
      'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
      'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
    // ...
  ],
```

**SRC:**

https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html

Answer (score 2):

In Laravel Version - 4, HTML and Form existed, but not now.

**Why:**

The only reason is they have collected some user requirements and they want it more lightweight and so they removed it as in the sense that a user can add it manually.

**What to do to add HTML & Forms in Laravel 5.2 or 5.3:**

**For 5.2:**

Go to the [Laravel Collective site](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html) and installation processes have demonstrated their.

Like for 5.2: on the command line, run the command

```
composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.2.0"
```

Then, in the *provider* array which is in *config/app.php*. Add this line at last using a comma(,):

```
Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
```

For using HTML and FORM text we need to alias them in the *aliases array* of *config/app.php*. Add the two lines at the last

```
'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

**And for 5.3:**

Just run the command

```
composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.3.0"
```

And the rest of the procedure is like **5.2**.

Then you can use Laravel Form and other HTML links in your projects. For this, follow this documentation:

**5.2:** https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html

**5.3:**  https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html

***Demo Code:***

To open a form, open and close a tag:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'foo/bar']) !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

And for creating label and input text with a Bootstrap form-control class and other use:

```
{!! Form::label('title', 'Post Title') !!}
{!! Form::text('title', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
```

And for more, use the documentation, https://laravelcollective.com/.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Form`, not `form`. The capitalization counts.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried everything, but only this helped:

```
php artisan route:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```