# Laravel 5.4 Class 'form' not found

Tags: forms, laravel

I'm facing problem **'Class 'form' not found'**  I'm currently using laravel 5.4. I already have tried maximum efforts to solve.

Thanks

> Error is : Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

1/1

> FatalErrorException in d0b19e04e5a1f8a5507d8ca427362b23807103ca.php line 23:
>   Class 'Form' not found
>   in d0b19e04e5a1f8a5507d8ca427362b23807103ca.php line 23

Here is my Comp

```
{
    "require": {
       "php": ">=5.6.4",
       "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
       "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
       "laravelcollective/html": "^5.4"
    }, 
}
```

I run the composer update command.

Here is my app.php

```
'providers' => [

    /*
     * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
     */
    Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,
    'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',


    /*
     * Package Service Providers...
     */
    Laravel\Tinker\TinkerServiceProvider::class,

    /*
     * Application Service Providers...
     */
    App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    // App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,

],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Class Aliases
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This array of class aliases will be registered when this application
| is started. However, feel free to register as many as you wish as
| the aliases are "lazy" loaded so they don't hinder performance.
|
*/

'aliases' => [

    'App' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
    'Artisan' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
    'Auth' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
    'Blade' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::class,
    'Broadcast' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast::class,
    'Bus' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus::class,
    'Cache' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::class,
    'Config' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::class,
    'Cookie' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::class,
    'Crypt' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::class,
    'DB' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,
    'Eloquent' => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class,
    'Event' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::class,
    'File' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::class,
    'Gate' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate::class,
    'Hash' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::class,
    'Lang' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang::class,
    'Log' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,
    'Mail' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::class,
    'Notification' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification::class,
    'Password' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::class,
    'Queue' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue::class,
    'Redirect' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::class,
    'Redis' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
    'Request' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
    'Response' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::class,
    'Route' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,
    'Schema' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::class,
    'Session' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::class,
    'Storage' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class,
    'URL' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
    'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
    'View'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,
    'FORM' => 'Collective\Html\FormFacade',
    'HTML' => 'Collective\Html\HtmlFacade',
],

];
```

using form in formupload.blade.php

```
@if(isset($success))
    <div class="alert alert-success"> {{$success}} </div>
@endif
    {!! Form::open(['action'=>'ImageController@store', 'files'=>true]) !!}

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('title', 'Title:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('title', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('description', 'Description:') !!}
        {!! Form::textarea('description', null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'rows'=>5] ) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('image', 'Choose an image') !!}
        {!! Form::file('image') !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::submit('Save', array( 'class'=>'btn btn-danger form-control' )) !!}
    </div>

    {!! Form::close() !!}
    <div class="alert-warning">
        @foreach( $errors->all() as $error )
           <br> {{ $error }}
        @endforeach
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 Class 'form' not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28753767/laravel-5-class-form-not-found)

Comment: Please show these _"maximum efforts"_, start by showing some code and an expected result

Comment: Look at this [link](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html)

Comment: Hello Mr. R. Manzarei this link is only for 5.3 version I'm currently using 5.4.17 version of laravel

Comment: Hi @Shogunivar I have added  "require": {
       
        "laravelcollective/html": "^5.4"
    },
    to  composer.json     & added 'providers' => ['  'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',]        &  Add to  aliases   'FORM' => 'Collective\Html\FormFacade',
        'HTML' => 'Collective\Html\HtmlFacade', in   app.php also run composer update command in cmd

Comment: @hemant okay, well you will need to install that, by running composer install. But honestly, we can't help you if we can't see the code where it's going wrong. Edit your question with the code where you're trying to use a form

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you set the alias for your Form Class to "FORM" here in your app.php:

`'FORM' => 'Collective\Html\FormFacade',`

Try changing that to `Form` like so:

`'Form' => 'Collective\Html\FormFacade',`

then it should work

Comment: Hi @Shogunivar Thanks for giving me right answer. Yes, Its working fine. Its right answer. thanks again for great help.

Answer (score 17):

Put this in composer.json

```
"require": {
        "laravelcollective/html": "^5.4"
 },
```

and Run

```
composer update
```

in command afterwards

Or

```
composer require laravelcollective/html
```

Then add this in your config/app.php in providers section array

```
Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
```

After that add two class aliases in the config/app.php in aliases array

```
'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

Answer (score 0):

run command

```
 composer require laravelcollective/html
```

when the composer update the require html laravel collective 
then add these two line into config/app.php into the section of
  **'aliases' => [ ],**

```
'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

then add the line into config/app.php
**'providers' => [ ],** and save the file

```
Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the command

```
composer require laravelcollective/html
```

add these two lines into config/app.php into the section of
`'aliases' => [ ],`

```
'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

add the line into config/app.php
`'providers' => [ ]`, and save the file

```
Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
```

this also works for 6.X

Answer (score 0):

class aliases in the `config/app.php`

```
'Form' => 'Collective\Html\FormFacade',
```

this is working for me