# Laravel5- Class 'Form' not found

Tags: php, html, laravel-5

Was just trying to create a simple form in Laravel
Class 'Form' not found in signup.blade.php

This is web.php

```
Route::get('signup', function ()
{
   return view('signup');
});
```

This is signup.blade.php

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'thanks')) }} //Here
   {{Form::label('email','Email Address')}}
   {{Form::text('email')}}

   {{Form::select('os', array(
       'linux' => 'Linux',
       'mac' => 'Mac OS X',
       'windows' => 'Windows'
   ))}}

   {{Form::label('comment','Comments')}}
   {{Form::textarea('comment','', array('placeholder' => 'What are your 
      interests?'))}}

   {{Form::checkbox('agree', 'yes', false)}}
   {{Form::label('agree', 'I agree to your terms of service')}}

   {{Form::submit('signup')}}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

Have i missed any `use` or `include` statements or whats wrong here
Thank you!

Comment: if's bit different from this i guess

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using..?

Comment: it's laravel5..

Comment: The `Form` facade was removed from Laravel 5 and the community maintained project should be used: https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html

Comment: Read First Line of this answer.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37243805/5350773

Comment: Yup this is a duplicate but lol even that question was bit complecated for me to understand thanx men!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install and configure https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html. Don't forget to add the form alias.

Comment: thanx man i fixed it!