# how to retrieve select options from my database

Tags: forms, select, laravel-5

I'm trying to retrieve my select option from 3 databases located in a connection that's not my defaut connection.

but I'm getting an error : Undefined variable: marqs (View: C:\wamp64\www\projetSovac\resources\views\home.blade.php)

Here's my controller code

```
   public function index()
{

    $marques= DB::connection('sqlsrv2')->table('marque')->get();
    $modeles = DB::connection('sqlsrv2')->table('Modele')->select( DB::raw('CodeModele'))->get();
    $finitions = DB::connection('sqlsrv2')->table('finition')->select( DB::raw('CodeFinition'))->get();


    $marqs = $marques->all(['marque']);
    $models = $modeles->all(['CodeModele']);
    $Finitions = $finitions->all(['CodeModele']);
    return View::make('home')

        ->with(compact($marqs))

        ->with(compact($models))

        ->with(compact($Finitions));
    return View('home');
}
```

and my home.blade.php code

```
  <tr class="filters">
                        <th><input type="text" class="form-control daterangepicker-field" placeholder="Période d'analyse" disabled ></th>
                        <th><select class="form-control "  disabled>
                                {!! Form::Label('marque', 'marque:') !!}
                                @foreach($marqs as $marque)
                                    <option value="{{$marque->codeMarque}}">{{$marque->codeMarque}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </th>
```

Can you help identify the problem?
Thanks

Comment: It is complaining about `{!! Form::Label('marque', 'marque:') !!}` are you sure Form is in `config/app.php` => `aliases` ?

Comment: Does `{!! \Form::Label('marque', 'marque:') !!}` work for you ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 Class 'form' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28753767/laravel-5-class-form-not-found)

Comment: No it's not working! I've just added Form in my config/app.php and I guess I should run this command too `composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.4"`

Comment: Maybe this solves your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28753767/laravel-5-class-form-not-found ?

Comment: @Mike I've edited my error : **Undefined variable: marqs (View: C:\wamp64\www\projetSovac\resources\views\home.blade.php)**

Comment: `compact($marqs)` wants to have a string divining the variable you want to pass to the view. Use:  `compact('marqs')` you can also combine your variables like `compact('marqs', 'models', ....etc )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`compact($marqs)` wants to have a string divining the variable you want to pass to the view. Use: `compact('marqs')` you can also combine your variables like `compact('marqs', 'models', ....etc )`

Also you are returning something 2 times now in the function this is not possible.

I would rewrite your function to be like this:

```
$marques= DB::connection('sqlsrv2')->table('marque')->get();
$modeles = DB::connection('sqlsrv2')->table('Modele')->select( DB::raw('CodeModele'))->get();
$finitions = DB::connection('sqlsrv2')->table('finition')->select( DB::raw('CodeFinition'))->get();

$marqs = $marques->all(['marque']);
$models = $modeles->all(['CodeModele']);
$Finitions = $finitions->all(['CodeModele']);
return View::make('home')->with(compact('marqs', 'models', 'Finitions'));
```

Assuming the first 6 lines get you the actual data all i changed was the return.

You might want to read up on how to use laravel models
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent

I am not sure if u have defined any but it could make your code allot simpler.